# Object only being drawn when the game window is dragged around

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to recreate Agar.io in Python using pygame. So far I've been able to somewhat simulate the player movement, but then I tried to generate some "food cells" at a given interval using the pygame.time.set_timer() method, but even though the rest of the game elements are being drawn, such as the screen and the player, these food cells are only drawn (and added to the "food_list" list) when I drag the game window around. I think this might be an issue of me not really knowing how to deal with the event queue.

main.py, which is where the game loop is located:

```
import sys, pygame
from player import Player
from food import Food
import random
pygame.init()

SCREEN_SIZE = [1024, 768]
WHITE = (255, 255 , 255)
generate_food = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
screen.fill(WHITE)

player = Player()
food_list = []

## TODO: Make a separate GameScreen class.
## TODO: Make a list of constants

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == generate_food:
            food_x = random.randrange(0, 760)
            food_y = random.randrange(0, 1000)
            food_list.append(Food(food_x, food_y))

    pygame.time.set_timer(generate_food, 200)
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    for f in food_list:
        f.draw(screen)

    player.update()
    player.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

food.py:

```
import pygame
import random
from cell import Cell

DARK_GREEN = (0, 102, 0)

class Food(Cell):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.size = 2
        self.image = pygame.Surface([2, 2])
        self.image.fill(DARK_GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, DARK_GREEN, (self.x, self.y), self.size, 0)

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y
```

Comment: I've just done a quick pass but it seems this line `pygame.time.set_timer(generate_food, 200)` that sets the timer is going to happen each time you go through your main while loop, resetting the timer and so never generating food.  That should be put behind something like `if(gamejuststarted)` and then added in to the `if event.type == generate_food:` statement to restart the timer once food generates

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the timer is restarted continuously in the application loop. However [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) crates a timer that repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. Hence it is sufficient to start the timer once before the application loop:

```py
pygame.time.set_timer(generate_food, 200)          # <--- ADD

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == generate_food:
            food_x = random.randrange(0, 760)
            food_y = random.randrange(0, 1000)
            food_list.append(Food(food_x, food_y))

    # pygame.time.set_timer(generate_food, 200)      <--- DELTE
```